# Powershell: how to retrieve formula without iterating through all row and columns?

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-2003

Here is my sample code:

```
$wb = $excel.ActiveWorkbook

ForEach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets) {
    "Working on {0}" -f $ws.Name
    forEach ($row in $ws.Rows) {
        forEach($cell in $row.Cells) {
            if ($cell.HasFormula) {
                $formula = $cell.Formula
                if ( ($formula -match "foobar") {                
                    "{0} R{1}C{2}:{3}" -f $ws.Name, $row.Row, $cell.Column, $formula
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The performance is not good because the spreadsheet is too big. I want to

1) can I retrieve all formula in one function call? Does excel support it?

2) In the case a formula is assigned to an array of cells, how can I extract the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this [link](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip37.htm) can give you some hints to get a list of formulas in a sheet.

```
$excel = New-Object -com Excel.Application
$excel.Workbooks.Open( "C:\cartel1.xls" )
$sheet = $excel.Sheets.item(1) # select the sheet to looking for formulas
$cellsWithFormula = $sheet.Cells.SpecialCells( -4123 , 23) # (XlCellType constant, XlSpecialCellsValue constant) - Return a Range of cell with formula
$cellsWithFormula |  select row, column, formula, formulaArray | ft -autosize # get a list of cell and formula and formulaArray
```

note:  [type xlCell Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213567%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: This is a great answer! A slight catch: "WARNING: column "FormulaArray" does not fit into the display and was removed.". FormatTable does not like FormulaArray.

Comment: @AnthonyKong. try | Ft -autosize | out-string -width 4096 | set-content c:\list.txt for have all column in a text file. If a column doesn't fit in a display with -autosize wil be truncated (not only formulaarray but any column out of display size!.